# cmd netstat via java cant run

Tags: java, cmd, netstat

I want to count established connection on java, I run the following command(windows) on cmd and I get the right output:

```
netstat -an | find /c "EST"
```

But when I tried to run this command via java I cant.

My code:

```
        String executed = "netstat -an | find \"EST\" ";
        System.out.println(executed);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executed);

        String s = null;
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("DONE");
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: The pipe `|` is handled by `cmd.exe`, not by the OS, so you have to either run the line using `cmd.exe /c "netstat -an | find /c EST", *or* do the `find` in Java and just run `netstat -an` itself. I'd suggest the second.